# Is there no way to assign parent vertex when making vertex parent in object mode?

Tags: parent

Studying 'vertex parent' yesterday, I found a strange thing.

What that means is that making vertex parent in object mode is different from edit mode.

Way in edit mode: we select child object and shift select parent object(now active object) and convert it to edit mode and ***assign parent vertex*** and ctrl+p.

But in object mode there's no process to assign parent vertex.

It is very strange to me that exactly same operation(make vertex parent) differs(one can assign parent vertex manually and the other can't) in two modes.

Is there no way to assign parent vertex when making vertex parent in object mode?

Comment: sorry it's not clear to me, what are you talking about when you say making vertex parent in Object mode? By definition you can't, as in Object mode you can't select any vertex... could you please reformulate?

Comment: @moonboots [link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/relations/parents.html?highlight=parent#vertex-parent-from-object-mode) here two mode is described. It says that **Vertex Parent from Object Mode**:_Vertex parenting can be performed from object mode_, this is done like regular object parenting, press Ctrl-P in object mode and select Vertex or Vertex (Triangle).  
 _

Comment: oh ok I've never used that way, but I still don't see the problem, with this second method, first select a vertex in the parent object, then go back in Object mode, then select the child, then shift select the parent, then ctrl P > Vertex

Comment: @moonboots If you do make vertex parent as you said , you'll find that the vertex you selected at first would never be parent vertex. Instead nearest vertex from child object would be selected as a parent vertex automatically.

Comment: @moonboots In other words, you can't assign parent vertex in object mode while you can in edit mode. I think that this is very strange.

Comment: Yes you right I didn't notice, so this must be a bug and this second method doesn't work or doesn't work anymore, maybe someone knows, but anyway the first method works

Comment: @moonboots  ok. have a nice day!

Comment: actually it parents but with some other vertices than the selected ones